# Find vector coordinates of triangle by the cathetus and the angle

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

[image]

Hello! Here is the problem: There is a right triangle with vertices **A**, **B**, **C** in a cartesian coordinate system, where coordinates of points **A** and **B** and the angle **a** and **b** (90°) given.
How to find the coordinates of vertex **C**?

The main problem is to find the coordinates of a point on a rectangle, knowing the radius of the incircle and the angle.

Comment: Do you know about the triangle definition of the trigonometric functions? In particular, can you express the tangent $\tan a$ in terms of the side length $x = |BC|$ and the radius $r = |AB|$? That equation will give you your $x$-coordinate. Your $y$-coordinate is even more straightforward.

Comment: By the way, welcome to Math.SE! What have you tried? What do you know that might be useful? Where did you get stuck? Peruse [this guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) to asking a good question on this site, and edit your question to include more info in order to get better answers!

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not good at trigonometry, so I don't even know what to look for (at most, I can find a point on a circle :).
Thank you, I will try to understand your answer.

Comment: @SammyBlack - your descrption works when $A$ is the origin and $B$ is on the $y$ axis. When $A$ and $B$ are arbitrary, then you need to take additional steps. (But finding $x$ as you describe is still the first step). VeroLom - this problem clearly expects you to be conversant with basic trigonometry. If Sammy Black's explanation is troubling to you, then you clearly need to brush up on the prerequisites to this subject. If you try to muddle forward without improving your skills on this, you will just end up falling farther behind. Get the prerequisites down first, then come back to this.

Answer (score 0):

The ratio $\space r=\dfrac{BC}{AB}\space$ is the tangent of this triangle. In an artificial construction, we let
$\space\angle a= 22.62˚\space$ and $\space AB=12.\quad$
We let $r=\tan 22.62˚\approx0.416669\space$ and we find $\space BC=12r\approx 5.\quad$ The final coordinates are $\space (x,y)\approx(5,12).$